# cmake: link local build of library/package to build another library

Tags: cmake

I need to give the path to the local build of a library (in my case :Eigen) to build PCL library locally on my lab machine.
I do not have root privileges and cant do 'sudo make install'. so i need to build the PCL library locally on my lab machine. PCL has dependent libraries like Eigen and Flann... how can I give the path of these local builds while building PCL locally?

I was able to build Eigen locally on the machine as:
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/localEigen

i need to give the path of this local build in the cmake for PCL.
I tried this but it fails to find Eigen:
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/i7264040/localPCL/ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR:PATH=/home/i7264040/localEigen/include/

Need help badly...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has two parts:

1. For the Eigen library, define `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to somewhere where you can install it without needing privilegies. Build and install Eigen.
2. For the dependent library:

   - if it has some setting for where to look for Eigen, set it to the install prefix of Eigen (often environment variable; unfortunately cmake does not have any standard for providing library-specific paths), otherwise
   - set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the value of install prefix given to Eigen.